# Laptop WIll Not Power On After Installing Hard Drive

Tags: laptop, power

I was given an HP Pavilion 15 laptop that was believed to be in need of a hard drive. I installed a drive I had on hand, but, afterward, the PC would not power on (it did before it was taken apart for the replacement). It did not take long to figure out that the cable connecting the power button to the board had gotten ripped in the process. As I am not comfortable with soldering,

I purchased a replacement power button (HP DA0U83PB6E0) and installed it. However, the machine still appears to have no power. The light on the power button does not come on. There is no sound. I have tried hooking it up to the charger just in case, but without success. No light comes on when charger is connected.

As stated previously, it powered on before the hard drive was installed (and the power button cable was ripped), so I am presuming the motherboard itself is still good. Are there any other parts / disconnected cables (aside from the battery and power button) that could cause this behavior, or did I possibly make a mistake during my install of the power button? What steps might I perform to troubleshoot the issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you made sure all screws are firmly secured? Also check for debris that can short-circuit your laptop's motherboard. If all comes up clean, try and boot the laptop with no memory installed. If the computer beeps, the motherboard is alive. If there is no beep, most likely you have killed your motherboard while installing the hard disk.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into it. This may sound stupid, but I did not realize that loose or absent screws could cause such an issue. To be honest, I just put the thing back together quickly for testing purposes, so I know not all the screws were in there right.

Comment: Does it power up if you remove the hard drive? I think this may be a red herring - and the problem. I wonder if a ribbon cable has been unseated?

Comment: I'm wondering if the actual power supply is dead myself...

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I did try removing the hard drive. Unfortunately, no success. Is there any to rule out a certain component (for example the power supply or motherboard) as the issue? There is absolutely no indication of "life". No sound, no light, with the charger or without. Thanks again. I suppose it is possible (albeit unlikely) that the power button I ordered is defective. Is there anyway to test the unit without another laptop?